# How to compress HTML output except on a certain div?

Tags: php, disqus

I'd like to use this function:

```
ob_start('no_returns');
 function no_returns($a) { 
  return str_replace(
   array("\r\n","\r","\n","\t",'','',''), 
   '', $a);
 }
```

But when I do, it completely kills Disqus comments so I'd like to ignore the DIV "disqus_thread". How would I go about doing that without using some heavy search?

Comment: I have to ask why you are doing this? I recommend compressing your content instead (via apache+gzip/mod_deflate or another web server). Doing this via PHP is extra unnecessary overhead (IMO).

Comment: Why do you even call it 'compression'?

Comment: Although you could certainly skip the Disqus DIV with some smart regex, I wonder if you're doing the smart thing. If your goal is to send less bytes over the wire, then you'll be much more effective by enabling actual compression in your webserver or by using php's ob_gzhandler.

Comment: I am already doing all of that.

Comment: @Ryan Doherty: IIRC, mod_deflate doesn't normally handle PHP output - you need to use the obgzhandler - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to speed up the download of the web page, you might try another method:

```
<?php

ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
// html code here
```

This will compress the output in a much more efficient manner and your browser will automatically decompress the output in real-time before the visitor sees it.

A related thread on-line is here: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/621308-compress-html-output-php

(This is the PHP way to compress web pages without using the webserver configuration. For example apache+gzip/mod_deflate on apache as mentioned above)

Comment: To ensure compatibility you should also use `header("Vary:Accept-Encoding");` which will serve the gzipped page only if the browser supports gzipped content.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)